# transfers character fields with packed data with ssis

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, ssis, binary

I am converting existing dts packages to ssis packages and I am running into issues with columns containing (what I thought was) packed data (comp-3 ?).

**Edit: turns out the it wasn't packed data but binary zeros.**

The source is in a SQL 2005 database.  The column is datatype char(100) containing a comp-3 packed field. This originated from a COBOL program. Multiple values are stored in this one string. For example, substring(myfield,39,8) may contain a string representing a date. The collation is Latin1_General_BIN

The destination is a SQL 2008 database.  The column datatype can be changed but right now it is a varchar(100).  The collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

The original dts worked correctly.  In the destination database, substring(myfield,39,8) still returns a date string of "20140425".  However, when I tried migrating it to ssis, this field is an empty string.  substring(myfield,39,8) returns an empty string.

Here is the hex value of the data from the original datasource: 
0x20202020202000000000000000000000000020202020202020202020202020202020202020203230313430343235202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200000000020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020

Here is the hex value after it is transferred to the destination: 0x202020202020

Something in the ssis seems to be converting the data before putting it in the destination table. How do I prevent this and copy exactly what is in the source database?

Comment: 100 is not divisible by eight. 38 is not divisible by eight. If you are getting `2014050` from a simple substring then the data is not packed-decimal (how would substring know about that?). As far as I can see, there is a lack of internal consistency with your description. Can you provide an example, shown in hex, of the first 16 bytes of one of these char(100) values?

Comment: Here is the hex value from the original datasource 0x20202020202000000000000000000000000020202020202020202020202020202020202020203230313430343235202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200000000020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020  here is the hex value after it is transferred to the destination 0x202020202020

Comment: Can you use the edit link under your question to put this into your question. It may get missed in the comments.

Comment: There is no packed-decimal (comp-3) data in what you have shown. You have a couple of sets of binary zeros. Starting from position 39, you do indeed have character values which should give you `20140425` in that example. Why it should otherwise appear as space is an interesting question. To convince yourself, do a similar thing (use substring) on a char column in a test database just to get something out which is non-blank. If successful, update the data to include that first run of binary zeros (7 for 12, I think, but you check) and see if it works. If it does, look to your code.

Comment: Thanks. I found this which should hopefully lead me to a solution.  I appreciate your help!!! http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/948ad2c3-a9d5-45eb-961b-ee44fd54ddbe/problem-importing-text-files-with-binary-zeros-0x00-via-ssissql2005-it-is-all-fine-when-using?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Well done, looks like a good hit. If you get a resolution, you should write up an Answer to the question, and Accept it. It will then help others coming up against similar problems. You won't get reputation from the Accept for a self-answered question, but you can still get reputation from Upvotes (I'll keep an eye open to give you a hand there, and then I'll remove the COBOL tag). Upvoted the question. An interesting find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help from @BillWoodger, I found that the issue was not actually with packed data but the data contained binary zeros.  Some googling led me to this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/948ad2c3-a9d5-45eb-961b-ee44fd54ddbe/problem-importing-text-files-with-binary-zeros-0x00-via-ssissql2005-it-is-all-fine-when-using?forum=sqlintegrationservices) which says that a binary 0 is handled differently between dts and ssis.  In sql server 2005 ssis, a binary 0 is treated as an end of string character so everything after it is truncated.

My solution was to convert the original column to varbinary(100) in my source sql query and then add a script tranformation with vb.net to strip out the binary 0.

source query

```
select cast(mycolumn as varbinary(100)) as mybinary
```

vb.net tranformation

> ```
>     Dim hexValue As Integer
>     Dim finalStr As String
>     finalStr = ""
>
>     For i As Integer = 0 To Row.mybinary.Length - 1
>         hexValue = Row.mybinary(i)
>         If (hexValue = 0) Then
>             finalStr = finalStr + " "
>         Else
>             finalStr = finalStr + System.Convert.ToChar(hexValue)
>         End If
>     Next
>
>     Row.outColumn = finalStr
> ```

Here's another [link](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/removing-null-characters-0x00-from-values-in-sql-server/) that was helpful but didn't work for me b/c it eliminated some extra characters.